# Proportionally resize a bitmap

Tags: android

I've got a bitmap... and if the bitmap's height is greater than maxHeight, or the width is greater than maxWidth, I'd like to proportionally resize the image so that it fits in maxWidth X maxHeight.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
    BitmapDrawable bmp = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), PHOTO_PATH);

    int width = bmp.getIntrinsicWidth();
    int height = bmp.getIntrinsicHeight();

    float ratio = (float)width/(float)height;

    float scaleWidth = width;
    float scaleHeight = height;

    if((float)mMaxWidth/(float)mMaxHeight > ratio) {
        scaleWidth = (float)mMaxHeight * ratio;
    }
    else {
        scaleHeight = (float)mMaxWidth / ratio;
    }

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

    Bitmap out = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getBitmap(), 
            0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

    try {
        out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, 
                new FileOutputStream(PHOTO_PATH));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        fnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the following exception:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you past the corrected code here? I am getting same exception

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your scaleWidth and scaleHeight should be scale factors (so not very big numbers) but your code seems to pass in the actual width and height you're looking for.  So you're ending up massively increasing the size of your bitmap.

I think there are other problems with the code to derive scaleWidth and scaleHeight as well though.  For one thing your code always has either *scaleWidth = width* or *scaleHeight = height*, and changes only one of them, so you're going to be distorting the aspect ratio of your image as well.  If you just want to resize the image then you should just have a single *scaleFactor*.

Also, why does your if statement check for, effectively, *maxRatio > ratio* ?  Shouldn't you be checking for *width > maxWidth* or *height > maxHeight*?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the value of `scaleWidth` or `scaleHeight` is too large,`scaleWidth` or `scaleHeight` is mean enlarge or shrink 's rate,but not `width` or `height`,too large rate lead to `bitmap` size exceeds 32 bits

```
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how i did it:

```
public Bitmap decodeAbtoBm(byte[] b){
    Bitmap bm; // prepare object to return

    // clear system and runtime of rubbish
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();  

    //Decode image size only
    BitmapFactory.Options oo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    // only decodes size, not the whole image
    // See Android documentation for more info.
    oo.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length ,oo);

    //The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE=200;

    // Important function to resize proportionally.
    //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int scale=1;
    while(oo.outWidth/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE
            && oo.outHeight/scale/2>=REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale*=2; // Actual scaler

    //Decode Options: byte array image with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize=scale; // set scaler
    o2.inPurgeable = true; // for effeciency
    o2.inInputShareable = true;

    // Do actual decoding, this takes up resources and could crash
    // your app if you do not do it properly
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length,o2);

    // Just to be safe, clear system and runtime of rubbish again!
    System.gc();
    Runtime.getRuntime().gc();

    return bm; // return Bitmap to the method that called it
}
```